# Taking back up of files while using Copy & Paste via command line

Tags: shell, copy, command

I am using the command `cp -a <source>/* <destination>` for copying and pasting the files inside one particular destination. In the destination the above command only replaces the files inside a folder that is present in source as well. If the there are other files present in destination, the command will not do anything and leave as it is. Now before doing the pasting, I want to take the back up of the files that are about to be replaced with the copy paste. Is there an option in the cp command that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to backup these files that will be copied from *source*, use -b option, available in GNU cp

```
cp -ab <source>/* <destination>
```

There is 2 caveats that you should know about.

- This command, in my knoledge, is not available in non GNU
  system (like BSD systems)
- It will ask for confirmation for each existing file in target. We can reduce the probleme with the -u option but this is unusable in a script.

It appears to me that you are trying to make a backup (copy files to another location, don't erase them, don't overwrite those already in them), you probably want to take a look at the rsync command. This same command would be written

```
rsync -ab --suffix=".bak" <source>/ <destination>
```

and the rsync command is much more flexible to handle this sort of things.

Comment: Thanks. This is the exact solution that I require. Instead of bak, I have added the time stamp in the suffix.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such option in `cp` command. Here you need to create a shell script. First execute a `ls` command in your destination directory and store the output in a file like `history.txt`. Now just before `cp` command execute a `grep` command with the file you want to copy in the `history file` to check whether that file is already available in history file or not. If the file is available in destination directory (that means file available in `history file`) back up the file in destination directory first with todays datestamp and then copy the same file name from source to destination.

Comment: Ok. One small doubt, if there are subfolders present inside the destination directory, will that work?

Comment: Do you want to copy a directory like `cp -R directory ./path/directory`? if so you have to put condition to check whether it is a directory or a file. If directory you have to use -R option in `cp` command.